# SLOW RESPONSE ON REST API BUT Good AT WEB PAGE

Tags: php, mysql, performance-testing, varnish

I am from india and I am migrating a Ecommerce application from an old server to New Server .

I am using postman to see the API response.New Server Response high as compared to OLD server although NEW Server RAM is Double than the Old Server

Files and Database both are on Separated Server

[image]

**Old Server**

Server Location : Delhi (INDIA)

RAM : 6 GB

Processor : 2 CORE

Response Time : 6738 ms

OS : Centos 6

**NEW Server**

Server Location : Singapore

RAM : 12 GB

Processor : 4 CORE

Response Time : 9238 ms

Centos : 6

APACHE/MYSQL Configuration are almost same.

I have installed VARNISH for cache on NEW SERVER ... OLD SERVER DO not have VARNISH..

When I am browsing the application on WEB then the response time is better than my OLD SERVER

We are a ANDROID application , we do have REST APIs for the application but the response it HIGH , keeping in mind that the Server Capability is double of the OLD server.

Please find the screenshot... I have mentioned the Response time of BOTH OLD and NEW server.

Comment: It could be that your database queries are not optimized. You can see if you can add indexes on columns where you're doing joins.

Also, see if your database is configured in a way that allows it to use more of the server's resources.

Comment: I am having the same database.. Imported the same database..

Comment: Perhaps you should get a database specialist to look at MySql config, and your programmers can check for indexes and possible optimizations of queries.